# How do I override silent mode and play sound in notification extension?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to achieve something like find my iPhone app. Even when in the killed state it will play sound at full volume.
I don't want to use VOIP calls to do it because my app doesn't need it so it might get rejected.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler
    bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    
    let songTitle = "ping"
    let songExtension  = "mp3"
    
    
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "\(songTitle)", withExtension: "\(songExtension)")  {
        
        let volumeView = MPVolumeView()
        if let view = volumeView.subviews.first as? UISlider{
            view.value = 1.0 //---0 t0 1.0---
            
        }
        
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, options: .mixWithOthers)
            
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: data, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)
            audioPlayer.volume = 1.0
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer.play()
        } catch let error {
            print("[SoundPlayer] There was an error: \(String(describing: error))")
        }
        
        if (audioPlayer.isPlaying) {
            audioPlayer.stop()
        }
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
    
    if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
        // Modify the notification content here...
        bestAttemptContent.title = "\(bestAttemptContent.title) [modified]"
        
        contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        
        
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to debug the app I get a crash with error:
**Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=561015905 "(null)"**

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. Apple can override the silent switch for an emergency situation like finding the device. You are not Apple so you cannot get a special dispensation for your notification to play sound that overrides the silent switch.

Comment: Hi Matt, I came across criticalAlertSetting which can help achieve my goal: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsettings/2963116-criticalalertsetting
The approach I was going with was wrong.